# Some events are displayed but some others not in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, python, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm having a problem trying to display events on FullCalendar. Some events are displayed and others not.

I fill the FC via [JSON](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) and until now was working well even with the pagination to only retrieve the events of the selected month.

```
...
events: {
    url: '/getEvents',
    method: 'GET',
    failure: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        alerta("Error", "Ups...", "red");
    },
},
...
```

But now I'm trying to add more events from other stuff stored on the DB and, despite construct them on the same way, they are not shown on the calendar.

I construct the events like this (I've sanitized the code):

```
rows = connection.execute("SELECT...........")
events = []
for row in rows:
    event = {"id": row['id'], "title": row['title'], "start": row['start'], "end": row['end'], "allDay": row['allDay'], "url": row['url'], "color": row['color'], "extendedProps": {"company": row['company'], "state": fila['state']}}
    if row['groupId'] is not None:
        event['groupId'] = str(row['groupId'])
   events.append(event)
```

Now, on other part of the program I create events in a similar way:

```
more_rows = connection.execute("SELECT....")
more_events = []
for row in more_rows:
    event = {"id": row['id'], "title": row['title'], "start": row['start'], "end": row['end'], "allDay": 1, "url": "", "color": row['color'], "extendedProps": {"company": row['company'], "description": row['description'], "type": row['type'], "tecnology": row['tecnology'], "state": row['state']}}
    more_events.append(event)
```

They are sent together to the browser:

```
...
events.extend(more_events)
return jsonify(events), 200
...
```

The `jsonify(events)` sends to the browser this JSON (I use double quotes on python code, but jsonify replaces it to single quotes):

```
[{'allDay': 1, 'color': 'blue', 'end': '2019-10-24T00:00:00.000Z', 'extendedProps': {'company': 'Company test', 'state': 'Active'}, 'groupId': '48', 'id': 27, 'start': '2019-10-23T00:00:00.000Z', 'title': 'A title', 'url': ''}, 
{'allDay': 1, 'color': 'blue', 'end': '2019-10-11T00:00:00.00.000Z', 'extendedProps': {'company': 'Company test', 'description': 'oapisdvañklsjdhalksjdflaksjdf', 'state': 'Active', 'tecnology': 'javascript+html', 'type': 'Cool'}, 'id': 74, 'start': '2019-10-07T00:00:00.00.000Z', 'title': 'owqsakjdflh', 'url': ''}, 
{'allDay': 1, 'color': 'blue', 'end': '2019-10-23T00:00:00.00.000Z', 'extendedProps': {'company': 'Company test', 'description': 'sdgsdfgwertwertwg', 'state': 'Active', 'tecnology': 'c', 'type': 'Cool'}, 'id': 75, 'start': '2019-10-21T00:00:00.00.000Z', 'title': '1eqwrwqer', 'url': ''}, 
{'allDay': 1, 'color': 'blue', 'end': '2019-11-07T00:00:00.00.000Z', 'extendedProps': {'company': 'Company test', 'description': 'asdfafasdfasdfasdf', 'state': 'Active', 'tecnology': 'java', 'type': 'Cool'}, 'id': 76, 'start': '2019-11-04T00:00:00.00.000Z', 'title': 'Bla bla bla', 'url': ''}]
```

The thing is... the first element it's printed as an event but the rest of elements on the JSON are not printed.

I can't see where is my mistake or what I'm doing wrong.

Regards.

Comment: How are the contents of `events` and `more_events` serialised to JSON and returned to the browser? How are the two sets of data associated to the calendar? Are they included as separate event sources, perhaps? Your question is lacking quite bit of relevant code and context which would help us understand how and where the data might be going missing

Comment: P.s. are those literally your output strings? Because they are not valid JSON. A correctly written JSON serialiser would use double quotes round the property names and string values, not single quotes as you've done. It seems not to be a direct cause of your issue (most browsers are actually quite tolerant of deviations from the spec as long as it's comprehensible) but it's just worth noting. If you are building the JSON manually then..., well just don't. Use a serialiser. Python will have one built in, I expect

Comment: Hi @ADyson, thanks for your responses. I've updated the question, and even I use double quotes jsonify replaces it to single quotes. But even with single quotes, the first event it's printed anyway meanwhile the others aren`t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem (well, actually a co-worker) and it's here:

First element: `'end':'2019-10-24T00:00:00.000Z'` || `'start':'2019-10-23T00:00:00.000Z'`

The other elements: `'end': '2019-10-23T00:00:00.00.000Z'` || `'start': '2019-10-21T00:00:00.00.000Z'`

The thing is: 2019-10-24T**00:00:00**.000Z and 2019-10-23T**00:00:00.00**.000Z

I use this SQL to compare the dates (they are not stored on ISO 8601):

```
SELECT id, ....., strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%fZ', start_date) AS start, strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%fZ', end_date) AS end, ...... 
FROM table 
WHERE state = 'Active' AND start > '....' AND end < '....'
```

My problem was supose that **SQlite strftime** it's equal to **PYTHON strftime**, but nope.

I was using this (Python): '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:**%S.%f**Z' instead of this (SQlite): '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:**%f**Z'

[Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

```
%S Second as a zero-padded decimal number.
%f Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded on the left.
```

[Sqlite Doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

```
%S seconds: 00-59
%f fractional seconds: SS.SSS
```

So be carefull and **do not confuse the python format with the sqlite format**.

Regards!

Comment: well spotted, I hadn't noticed that!